# Bulk inserting new model instances using an hmt relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, activerecord

I have two models with a "has_many, through" relationship as defined by these definitions:

```
class TabAccount < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tab_community_accounts
  has_many :tab_communities, through: :tab_community_accounts
end

class TabCommunity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tab_community_accounts
  has_many :tab_accounts, through: :tab_community_accounts
end

class TabCommunityAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tab_community
  belongs_to :tab_account
end
```

I want to bulk add new accounts from a CSV file after I create a new community. This does not generate an error:

```
_upload_dir = <string>
_import_filename = <string>
_community_name = <string>
_this_community = TabCommunity.find_by_name(_community_name)

File.foreach("#{_upload_dir}/#{_import_filename}") do |csv_row_raw|
  csv_row = csv_row_raw.split(",")
  _screen_name = csv_row[0].strip
  _this_community.tab_accounts.first_or_create!({screen_name: _screen_name, ref_platform_id: RefPlatform.find_by_name("Twitter").id})
end
```

But it only inserts a new account and `hmt` relation for the first row from the CSV file. I want to use `.first_or_create()` because the account might already exist in the database. I added `put` statements inside the `foreach` before and after `.first_or_create()` and they do print for each row, but only the 1st row and its relation is saved in my database. Can anyone clue me in as to how I can dump the rest of the rows? I suspect I'm close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure if an account already exists or create otherwise by using `find_or_create_by!` on `TabAccount` model itself and assign it back to the `TabCommunity` relation like so:

```
acc = TabAccount.find_or_create_by!(
  screen_name: _screen_name, 
  ref_platform_id: RefPlatform.find_by_name("Twitter").id
)
_this_community.tab_accounts << acc unless _this_community.tab_accounts.include?(acc)
```